# iPhone 6 - App icons disappeared, lost a lot of features

Tags: error, repair

My sister's iPhone 6 stopped working properly after she turned it off back on (that is what she stated).

Some icons disappeared and some turned white. We are unable to delete the apps. We already tried to reset and hard reset. The settings app is gone. We tried to look for it with the search tool and Siri, but is throws error, saying that the URL couldn't be found.

We tried to connect to a computer, but it doesn't connect neither. The computer says that the iPhone didn't allow access. I'll include some pictures, as it doesn't even allow us to share screenshots.

What is the possible issue with the iPhone and how do I proceed to resolve it?

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: Hi Leonardo, welcome to Ask Different. Something seems to be definitely wrong with your sister's iPhone 6. You could try to reset it to factory settings (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201274). Is the iPhone jailbroken? Then take a look at this: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-restore-your-iphone-from-a-jailbreak. If that doesn't help, I'd recommend that you take to an Apple Store or an authorized reseller.